# How do I make a personal call using Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I've read the Twilio phone call tutorial here: [https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/make-phone-calls-python.html](http://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/make-phone-calls-python.html)

Unlike the Twilio tutorial, which it does call my phone, but It only plays MP3 or a AI voice. I want to be able to make conversation. It there a way to connect my computer's microphone and speak to talk to my own phone using Twilio API? I've been search all over the internet and couldn't find a way. Please help.

Comment: Are you looking at the WebRTC docs?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, nice work getting through the tutorial and making a call. The URL from the tutorial (http://static.fullstackpython.com/phone-calls-python.xml) that you used produces the following [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml):

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">
    Thanks for testing out the Full Stack Python tutorial. Now adding you to the conference call!
  </Say>
  <Dial record="true">
    <Conference>Full Stack Python</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

This [speaks a message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) to you and then [dials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) you into a [conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).

Before moving onto connecting to your computer, can I point out first that you can connect this call to another phone number. All you'd need to do is replace the [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) in the TwiML with [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) and within that tag the number you want to call. This will connect your call to that other number.

If you want to connect this to your computer, you can use Twilio Client to build a phone within your browser using JavaScript. There is a [quick start tutorial for Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript) which will walk you through the early steps to getting that setup and I recommend you follow that.